# Disable Scrolling With Arrow Keys in Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, scroll

I have a flash embed code in my webpage. When playing the game, page is scrolling with Up and Down keys. How can i prevent this? Firefox is ok, but it's only scrolling in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A jQuery way of handling this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) e.preventDefault();
});
```

The page scrolls when the arrow keys (key 37-40) are hit (keydown) and when they're kept down (keypress). So, if this happens we prevent the default event by `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: make sure the swf is what has focus when the arrows are disabled though or you'll be removing some very useful functionality.